# [: : integer expression expected Error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am having issues with this script and don't know exactly what is happening.

```
#Main Menu
clear
while [ "$input" -eq "0" ];
do
clear
#$input == 0
echo "Hello, What would you like me to do?"
echo ""
echo "1 = ALL TEH THINGZ!"
echo "2 = Find the enemy postions and villages"
echo "3 = Set the firewalls to my liking"
echo "4 = Confuse the enemy"
echo "5 = Deploy the spies!"
echo "6 = DISABLED Run the TOP SECRET STUFF! (Note password is required)"
echo "81 = Burn the bridges! (Cautian: Last Resort)"
echo "96 = Install/Update Software (locally)"
echo "97 = Install/Update Software (remotely)"
echo "98 = Update and add new Kali tools"
echo "99 = I am done with you for now"
read -p "Select an operation for me to do: " $input
```

I know I have the fi and end right but I am getting an error at the while [ "$input" -eq "0" ];

Comment: Also, replace `read -p "Select an operation for me to do: " $input` with `read -p "Select an operation for me to do: " input`

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- "use as little code as possible" (as opposed to having 90% of your code be `echo` statements unrelated to the problem). If you're "getting an error", provide the *exact* error in the question itself. Ideally, this could be just two lines -- one setting `input="something"` and another running `[ "$input" -eq "0" ]` (if the behavior of `read` were properly diagnosed and factored out of the problem).

Answer (score 7):

You'll get that message if `$input` is not a legal numeric expression; for instance, if it's the empty string.  If you want to loop while it's 0, you should start out by setting it to 0.

```
input=0
while [ "$input" -eq 0 ]; do 
...
done
```

Although you've tagged this `bash`; if you're actually using bash, you can also do this:

```
while (( input == 0 )); do
 ...
done
```

Note that shell is not Perl; the `$` is not part of the variable name.  It's better to think of `$` as an operator that means "get the value of".  The variable is `input`; you assign it with `input=`; you read into it with `read input`; *etc*.  You only use `$input` when you want to get *the value stored in* the variable.

So, for instance, it doesn't make sense to do `$input=` or `read $input` unless the value stored in the `input` variable is a string which is the name of some *other* variable that you want to set the value of.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is at

```
while [ "$input" -eq "0" ]
```

and you have not used the while loop closing statement `done`, too.

As you are comparing two strings, you should use

```
while [[ $input == 0 ]]; do <statements>; done
```

or

```
while [ $input = 0 ]; do <statements>; done
```

So your code will be:

```
#Main Menu
clear
echo -n "Select an operation for me to do: " 
read input

while [ $input = 0 ]
do
        clear
done

#$input == 0
echo "Hello, What would you like me to do?"
echo ""
echo "1 = ALL THE THINGZ!"
echo "2 = Find the enemy postions and villages"
echo "3 = Set the firewalls to my liking"
echo "4 = Confuse the enemy"
echo "5 = Deploy the spies!"
echo "6 = DISABLED Run the TOP SECRET STUFF! (Note password is required)"
echo "81 = Burn the bridges! (Cautian: Last Resort)"
echo "96 = Install/Update Software (locally)"
echo "97 = Install/Update Software (remotely)"
echo "98 = Update and add new Kali tools"
echo "99 = I am done with you for now"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the little-appreciated `select` command here. Replace the `:` command with the appropriate action.

```
choices=(
    'ALL TEH THINGZ!'
    'Find the enemy postions and villages'
    'Set the firewalls to my liking'
    'Confuse the enemy'
    'Deploy the spies!'
    'DISABLED Run the TOP SECRET STUFF! (Note password is required)'
    'Burn the bridges! (Cautian: Last Resort)'
    'Install/Update Software (locally)'
    'Install/Update Software (remotely)'
    'Update and add new Kali tools'
    'I am done with you for now'
)
PS3='Select an operation for me to do: '
echo 'Hello, What would you like me to do?'

select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case $choice in
        'ALL TEH THINGZ!')
            :
            ;;
        'Find the enemy postions and villages')
            :
            ;;
        'Set the firewalls to my liking')
            :
            ;;
        'Confuse the enemy')
            :
            ;;
        'Deploy the spies!')
            :
            ;;
        'DISABLED Run the TOP SECRET STUFF! (Note password is required)')
            :
            ;;
        'Burn the bridges! (Cautian: Last Resort)')
            :
            ;;
        'Install/Update Software (locally)')
            :
            ;;
        'Install/Update Software (remotely)')
            :
            ;;
        'Update and add new Kali tools')
            :
            ;;
        'I am done with you for now')
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```

You might want to look into using an associative array to construct a dispatch table.

Answer (score -4):

`-eq` works on integers only.

`$input` and `0` should not be in quotes.

To convert `$input` to integer, use `$((input))` instead.

You seem to be missing a `done` somewhere.

Comment: The quotation marks are not a problem; they do change the error message in this case, but if `input` held a numeric value, they would not get in the way at all.  Using `$((input))` would successfully turn the empty string into a 0, but that's just masking the issue, which is using an uninitialized variable.